# Why isn't my EditorFor datepicker field populating my value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, datepicker, editorformodel

I'm trying to get this datepicker field to populate with today's date but it's not happening for some reason. I can't find a reference for what options are accepted in the "new {}" section.

```
@Html.LabelFor(d => d.ServiceOn, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.EditorFor(d => d.ServiceOn, "DatePicker", new { disableMinDate = true, Value = DateTime.Today })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.ServiceOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

I've tried value, Value and @Value but the resulting html always shows value="". I'm wondering if maybe the datepicker itself is zeroing out the field. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: If I remember correctly, that is the expected functionality. EditorFor is going to set the value that's currently on your model " d.ServiceOn". You can try either using @html.Editor instead, set the value dynamically, or create your custom helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@Html.LabelFor(d => d.ServiceOn, new { @class = "control-label" })
@{Model.ServiceOn= DateTime.Today;}
@Html.EditorFor(d => d.ServiceOn, "DatePicker", new { disableMinDate = true })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.ServiceOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

`HTML` work with the `ModelState`, not from the model itself.

If you want more loose helpers, ise `@Html.Editor` instead.

Comment: The editor tells me that "c" doesn't exist in the current context. Is there something I should be inferring from it's use here?

Comment: Sorry, it should be Model. I've fixed it